# Git not storing credentials when sshed into server

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I have a ubuntu VM which I SSH into from a windows machine to develop on. I have my windows pub key on the linux VM so I can ssh without password.

On the linux machine I have set to store my git credentials. When I do any git command on the VM directly, it is able to use the stored credentials and carries out the given task. However, if I ssh into the VM from windows, and try to do any git command, it never stores the credentials and each time I have to reenter the password.

What is causing this and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: "*When I do any git command on the VM directly…*" "*However, if I ssh into the VM from windows…*" Compare the output of the command [`id`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/id) in these 2 cases. Compare the output of the command `echo $HOME`

Comment: Git credential helpers (such as `git-credential-store` or `git-credential-cache`) are used only with *https* URLs, not with ssh ones. To use ssh credentials, simply use ssh URLs: Git passes all the work off to ssh at that point, so anything else that happens is up to ssh and ssh-agents, so configure those as desired.

Comment: To check ssh agent status, use `ssh-add -l`. That will show you if ssh can connect to an agent at all, and then if it can, what key(s) are available.

Comment: @torek So I did the commands, and it appears that the ssh-agent is not running when sshing into the VM. If I start it manually, ssh-add doesnt have any of the keys. So I have to add it manually. However, if I close that ssh session and start a new one, I have to do the entire process again

Comment: You probably want to use *agent forwarding*. On a Unix system you'd run `ssh -A` or set this in the config file. I don't use Windows so I'm not sure if they have fiddled with this.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the output of `git config --show-scope --show-origin credential.helper` when:

- you are logged in directly on the Linux server
- you are logged in through SSH from Windows

This assumes that, in both instances, you are using an HTTPS URL from your Linux server when using git clone/push/pull to a remote server.

If the Git on Linux is not recent enough, use simply `git config --global credential.helper`.

Comment: This both showed the same output as store, the issue is that ssh-agent is not being started when I ssh into the system, and at the same time it losses all keys so I have to manually add it.

Comment: @ドヴィダスジリヴィス Once on Linux, are you using SSH or HTTPS URLs?